# Projeto possui mais de 65536 métodos

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-analytics-api

Ao adicionar o Pacote do Analytics no projeto, acabou ocorrendo um erro no projeto. Como explicado [neste blog](https://przemekraciborski.eu/2016/09/30/multidex-in-xamarin/#comments) , o erro ocorre quando o projeto possui mais de 65536 métodos (só o pacote do Google Play Services adicionado tem perto de 30 mil métodos). O mesmo link que explica o erro traz a solução, ativar o [Multi-dex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html?hl=pt-br#mdex-gradle).

Ao ativar o Multi-dex, outro erro ocorreu, The option for multi-dex fails when the path to the Android SDK contains a space, como a pasta do Android SDK está dentro de "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk" ocorre o erro por causa do "Program Files (x86)" que possuí espaços entre as palavras.

Alguém possui alguma solução?

Comment: Utilizar Windows para desenvolver software cedo ou tarde cai nesse problema.
Há a possibilidade reinstalar o sdk em outro local? C:\dev\ por exemplo ?

Comment: Acredito que possa mover, vou tentar!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Já tive este problema e para resolve-lo eu copiei o arquivo "android-sdk" para dentro do diretório C (C:\android-sdk) resolvendo o problema do espaço na URL.

Depois de copiar tu precisa atualizar os caminhos para o SDK:

No Visual Studio o caminho de localização do arquivo:

```
 Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Android SDK Location
```

No Xamarin Studio:

```
 Tools > Options > SDK Locations > Android > Android SDK
```

Após essa mudança acontece outro erro:

```
 "Unsupported class version number [52.0] (maximum 51.0, Java 1.7)".
```

Para resolvê-lo foi necessário atualizar o arquivo [proguard](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/) do android-sdk. Após baixar à última versão do arquivo, simplesmente renomeie o arquivo "proguard" já existente para um nome qualquer, descompacte o arquivo baixado dentro de "android-sdk" e altere seu nome para "proguard".